# Sed script behaves differently on similar platforms

Tags: gcc, sed, cygwin

I am building a project from Cygwin. Among other things, the GCC compiler creates dependency files, and then a sed script is called to "fix" the dependency files.

After the script finishes, on **one system** the dependency files contain, as example, this:

```
src/man/man.o: \[LF]
../include/debug.h \[LF]
../include/sys.h ../include/types.h \[LF]
```

and on the **another system** line endings are changed by the script to:

```
src/man/man.o: /[CR][LF]
../include/debug.h /[CR][LF]
../include/sys.h ../include/types.h /[CR][LF]
```

The second case with forward slashes and `[CR][LF]` breaks the build.

Why would the script behave differently?

Here is the critical sed line:

```
    @sed -i -e's/\\\(.\)/\/\1/g' $(@:.o=.d) ;\
```

Could anyone decipher why is it system dependent?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i -e's/\\\(.\)/\/\1/g'
```

Find a backslash (`\\`), followed by something (`.`) (i.e., not at end-of-line), and replace it with forward slash, plus whatever it was that followed (`\1`)...

```
$(@:.o=.d)
```

...in dependency files...? (Haven't seen this before, but it looks like "the corresponding `.d` for each `.o`.)

The rest looks unrelated to your problem.

I **guess** this is part of a crude way to turn Windows paths into Unix paths... and I **guess** the `<CR>` in there (no idea where *that* came from) makes this fail to operate correctly.

What happens if you add a `dos2unix` before that to get rid of the `<CR>`?

```
define DEPEND_HACK
    @dos2unix $(@:.o=.d) ;\
    sed -i -e's/\\\(.\)/\/\1/g' $(@:.o=.d) ;\
    ....
```

Comment: You are right, the ending [CR] confuses the script. After all, it looks like my dos-style line endings are the root cause, and I still need to find out why on my system line endings are different.